# Windows 7 PC browsers having trouble to open certain sites but not others

Tags: internet, browser

My Windows 7 PC these days acting very weird:

Examples:
It can not open Bing.com, alexa.com, msdn.Microsoft.com (blank page or page can not be found);
It can open zdnet.com but lost all CSS layouts and pictures;
It can open stackoverflow and Google no problem;

I tried all three browsers (Internet Explorer8, Chrome, Firefox 3.6) same thing.

I didn't change anything on this PC in days. 
This PC does have Anti-Virus installed and updated.
I'm also pretty sure it's not a network problem, because my other laptops are just fine at the same time.

The only thing I can think of is it might be some auto-update stuff underneath happened without my knowledge, but I have no idea where to troubleshoot?

Please shed some lights for me?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the ultimate reason is the proxy connection configuration of Internet Explorer.

Everything is fine once I uncheck all the checkboxes in the "automatic configuration" popup (Internet Explorer > Tools > Internet Options > Connections tab > LAN Settings button).

Comment: If you didn't add the proxy yourself you might want to run malwarebytes. Alot of spyware and virus's will change the IE proxy settings.